# Unity PlayerMovement Delayed Stopping

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I was making a PlayerMovement script today for a small 3D game I wanted to start. After some experimentation with the script, I realized that when you release a button to move, it won't instantly stop and instead the character body starts to slide.

For the most part, I had used Brackey's tutorial on PlayerMovement scripts but added a .Normalize() to make sure diagonals did not have more speed.

Does anyone know how to fix this? This is my PlayerMovement script.

```
public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour
{

    public float speed = 12f;
    public float gravity = -0.05f;
    public float jumpHeight = 4f;

    public Transform groundCheck;
    public float groundDistance = 0.4f;
    public LayerMask groundMask;

    Vector3 velocity;
    Vector3 move;
    private bool isGrounded;

    public CharacterController controller;

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        isGrounded = Physics.CheckSphere(groundCheck.position, groundDistance, groundMask);

        if (isGrounded && velocity.y < 0)
        {
            velocity.y = -2f;
        }

        float x = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        float z = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");

        Vector3 move = transform.right * x + transform.forward * z;
        move.Normalize();

        controller.Move(Time.deltaTime * speed * move);

        if (Input.GetButtonDown("Jump") && isGrounded)
        {
            velocity.y = Mathf.Sqrt(jumpHeight * -2f * gravity);
        }

        velocity.y += gravity * Time.deltaTime;

        controller.Move(velocity * Time.deltaTime);
    }
}
```

Thank you for any help or guidance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of Input.[GetAxis](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetAxis.html), try using Input.[GetAxisRaw](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetAxisRaw.html), which returns the non-smoothed value for a target axis, resulting in a more FPS-like controller, more responsive and fast, without smoothing.

Comment: Thanks! This did it, it's much more responsive.

Comment: Happy to be helpful.

Comment: Worked for me as well.